# Why might D3D11CreateDevice() have started throwing exceptions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, directx-11

Recently, a section of code that had worked fine previously has started throwing exceptions.  The relevant part of the function in question:

```
HRESULT DC11::TryCreateDevice(
    _In_ IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverType,
    UINT createDeviceFlags,
    _COM_Outptr_ ID3D11Device** ppDevice,
    _Out_opt_ UINT* pShaderModel,
    _COM_Outptr_ ID3D11DeviceContext** ppDeviceContext)
{
    UINT createDeviceFlags0 = 0;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags0 = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    if ((createDeviceFlags & createDeviceFlags0) != 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            "createDeviceFlags");
    }

    createDeviceFlags0 |= createDeviceFlags;

    SafeComPointer<ID3D11Device> device;

    SafeComPointer<ID3D11DeviceContext> deviceContext;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;

    HRESULT hr;

    hr = ::D3D11CreateDevice(
        pAdapter,
        driverType,
        nullptr,
        createDeviceFlags0,
        featureLevels,
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        device.GetAddressOf(),
        &featureLevel,
        deviceContext.GetAddressOf());

....
```

When I hit D3D11CreateDevice, I get

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007ffff54b3ce0 in CryptoNightTester.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff
```

which suggests to me a screwy pointer.  Bearing in mind that this section of code had not changed at all between when it worked and when it didn't, I was wondering if something had gone wrong with the pointer arguments.  I quickly confirmed that ppDevice and ppDeviceContext are what they should be, so I then looked at pAdapter.

In the surrounding calling code is

```
SafeComPointer<IDXGIFactory1> factory;

CHR(CreateDXGIFactory1(
    __uuidof(IDXGIFactory1),
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(factory.GetAddressOf())));

SafeComPointer<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;

HRESULT hr = factory->EnumAdapters1(
    0,
    adapter.GetAddressOf());

if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    return false;
}

CHR(hr);

DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 adapterDesc1;

hr = adapter->GetDesc1(&adapterDesc1);

FullHash mainLoopHasher;

mainLoopHasher.Create(
    adapter,
    5);

...

void FullHash::Create(
    _Inout_ SafeComPointer<IDXGIAdapter1>& adapter,
    _In_ uint32_t shaderModel)
{
    this->adapter.Swap(adapter);

    this->shaderModel = shaderModel;

    this->SetupShader();
}


void FullHash::SetupShader()
{
    UINT createDeviceFlags =
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED;

    bool deviceCreated = false;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    // try to enable performance counters
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUGGABLE;

    deviceCreated = DC11::TryCreateDevice(
        this->adapter.Get(),
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
        createDeviceFlags,
        this->device.GetAddressOf(),
        nullptr,
        this->deviceContext.GetAddressOf()) == S_OK;

....
```

which subsequently confirmed (so far as I could tell, anyway), that the adapter is what it should be.  The next thing I tested was what happens when I replace pAdapter with NULL in D3D11CreateDevice.  It no longer threw an exception, but hr was now E_INVALIDARG.

This is the point where I'm a little stuck.  My current best guess is recently installed/uninstalled software screwed something up.  Perhaps I need to reinstall an SDK or a driver or something?  I decided I'd post here before going that route as my system is ridiculously finicky when it comes to installing GPU drivers, so what would normally be an early resort must be a last resort.

For reference, I'm working on MSVS 2015 and have windows 10.

Edit:  expanded the calling code

Comment: How do you call `TryCreateDevice`? What are the input values? It is strange that you have a mix of raw and smart pointers. Maybe adapter gets released before being passed into function?

Comment: Edited to show more code.  Adapter does not get released before passing into the function.  Any thoughts on it returning E_INVALIDARG when passing NULL instead of the adapter pointer?  Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: *" if pAdapter == NULL, the DriverType cannot be set to D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN;"*

Comment: Ah.  Well, that answers that bit.